# How to map a sequence of vim commands to a shortcut?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I have the following sequence of vim commands I use to copy a function `va{Vy`, how can I map this to a shortcut key like F1? I'd also like to persist this.

Comment: https://vimhelp.org/usr_05.txt.html#05.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command would be:

```
nmap <F1> va{Vy
```

You can store this command in your ~/.vimrc file. This will make it persistent. If it does not exist simply create it.

More infos about this you can find [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)).

My question would be what should this command do? If you want to yank the current line the shortest commmand would be `yy`. If wou want to yank a paragraph (all text between an empty line) this does not work and the better command would be `vipy`. `vip` selects the current paragraph.

Comment: Well, the command is equivalent to `yVa{`, which yanks everything in `{` forced-linewise.

Comment: Also: prefer `nnoremap`